# Install extra rabbitmq plugin from github using bitnami/rabbitmq chart

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

**Goal**: Prepare a `values.yaml` file for the [rabbitmq chart provided by bitnami](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/rabbitmq), such that the plugin [rabbitmq-message-deduplication](https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication) is ready and available after running `helm install ...`

**Previous solution**: Currently, I am using the `stable/rabbitmq-ha` chart with the following `values.yaml`:

```yaml
extraPlugins: "rabbitmq_message_deduplication"

extraInitContainers:
  - name: download-plugins
    image: busybox
    command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
    args: ["
      wget
          -O /opt/rabbitmq/plugins/elixir-1.8.2.ez/elixir-1.8.2.ez
          https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication/releases/download/0.4.5/elixir-1.8.2.ez
          --no-check-certificate
      ;
      wget
          -O /opt/rabbitmq/plugins/rabbitmq_message_deduplication-v3.8.4.ez/rabbitmq_message_deduplication-v3.8.4.ez
          https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication/releases/download/0.4.5/rabbitmq_message_deduplication-v3.8.x_0.4.5.ez
          --no-check-certificate
      "]
    volumeMounts:
      # elixir is a dependency of the deduplication plugin
      - name: elixir
        mountPath: /opt/rabbitmq/plugins/elixir-1.8.2.ez
      - name: deduplication-plugin
        mountPath: /opt/rabbitmq/plugins/rabbitmq_message_deduplication-v3.8.4.ez

extraVolumes:
  - name: elixir
    emptyDir: {}
  - name: deduplication-plugin
    emptyDir: {}

extraVolumeMounts:
  - name: elixir
    mountPath: /opt/rabbitmq/plugins/elixir-1.8.2.ez
    subPath: elixir-1.8.2.ez
  - name: deduplication-plugin
    mountPath: /opt/rabbitmq/plugins/rabbitmq_message_deduplication-v3.8.4.ez
    subPath: rabbitmq_message_deduplication-v3.8.4.ez
```

This works A-OK. However, `stable/rabbitmq-ha` is going to disappear next month and so I'm migrating to `bitnami/rabbitmq`.

**Problem**: `bitnami/rabbitmq` expects `values.yaml` in a different [format](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/rabbitmq/values.yaml) and I can't for the life of me figure out how I should set up a new `values.yaml` file to achieve the same result. I've tried messing around with `command`, `args` and `initContainers` but I just can't get it done...

P.S. I have a cluster running locally using minikube. I don't believe this is relevant, but putting this here just in case.

**UPDATE:** Francisco's answer really helped. Somehow I missed that part of the documentation.

My new `.yaml` looks like this:

```yaml
communityPlugins: "https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication/releases/download/0.4.5/elixir-1.8.2.ez https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication/releases/download/0.4.5/rabbitmq_message_deduplication-v3.8.x_0.4.5.ez"

extraPlugins: "rabbitmq_message_deduplication"
```

It gets the plugin working just like I wanted, and with much less configuration. Good stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for choosing our chart! Our [[bitnami/rabbitmq]](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/rabbitmq) chart uses the parameter `communityPlugins` to install new plugins and `extraPlugins` to enable them. For example, to enable the `elixir` plugin you could try changing `values.yaml` to:

```yaml
communityPlugins: "https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication/releases/download/0.4.5/elixir-1.8.2.ez"

extraPlugins: "rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap elixir"
```

For more information, please look into the [Plugin section](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/rabbitmq#plugins) in our README and ask any more doubts if you need to!

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a slight change from Franciso De Paz Galan's post to fetch both of the ez files in the communityPlugins.

Both urls need to be as string with space delimited.

```
# Add the dedup community plugin
communityPlugins: 
  "https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication/releases/download/0.6.2/elixir-1.14.0.ez https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication/releases/download/0.6.2/rabbitmq_message_deduplication-0.6.2.ez"
extraPlugins: "elixir rabbitmq_message_deduplication"
```